# Is it possible for Electron builder MacOS codesigning to skip locale files?

Tags: electron, code-signing, electron-builder, electron-updater

3 quarters of my files in my .app are the default electron locale files, is it possible to remove them from the codesigning stage?

filepath e.g.:

```
./Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Resources/pl.lproj/locale.pak
./Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/gu.lproj/locale.pak
./Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Resources/pt_PT.lproj/locale.pak
```

I already tried specifing my `package.json` file with the following:

```
{
  "build":{
    "electronLanguages": "en", // or "en-US",
  }
}
```